# Maintaining Session State in Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How can I maintain users to get redirected to the same Server in a Load-Balanced Web Apps

Your answer will be very helpful

Comment: Are you looking how to set sticky sessions within the same data center?

Comment: If the scenario you're talking about is when you have scaled out your site to more than one instance, then you get the behavior you're looking for by default (see BenV's answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use Azure Traffic manager. When setup correctly it will route users to the proper cloud service in their region and provide them with the best possible experience.

More information can be found here

- [Azure Traffic Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/traffic-manager/)
- [Azure Traffic Manager Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/traffic-manager/)
- [Traffic Routing Methods](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-routing-methods/)

Answer (score 3):

Traffic Manager directs the user to the appropriate region, but assuming you have your web app scaled out to at least two instances, [ARR](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) (Application Request Routing) is what directs each request to a specific instance of the app.

ARR has a feature called Session Affinity which is enabled by default.  It uses an `ARRAffinity` cookie to attempt to route all requests from a client to the same instance of your application.  I say "attempt" because, the cloud being what it is, instances of your app can come and go due to autoscaling or maintenance activities.

[image: Azure load balancing]